# How can I make an material ui icon thinner

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make a material ui icon with a `+` thinner:

Here is how it look:

[image]

Here is how I want to achieve it:

[image]

```
<AddCircleIcon
  style={{ color: "#00B790", fontSize: 130 }}
/>
```

Comment: If you check the icon code, it generates an SVG image. You can make use of a tool like this to override the `path` element's d property
There is a way to reduce it: https://nimb.ws/nz8wM1 Try to use this tool to reduce the size and alignment: https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor/ 

Might not look standard but one of the ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can try to use this instead:

```
import Fab from '@material-ui/core/Fab';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';

<Fab color="primary" aria-label="add">
    <AddIcon />
</Fab>
```

Comment: How can I make the Fab bigger?

Comment: You can use size prop `size="large"` inside <Fab

Comment: If you want to customize Fab, you can try to add a className to Fab, e.g. `<Fab className="myFab" color="primary" aria-label="add">`, and then add whatever css style to that className in your style.css file.